# Всплывающее окно в javascript при onbeforeunload

Tags: javascript

Собственно есть страничка с формой, которую пользователь старательно заполнял, а потом случайно кликнул не туда и все его труды потерялись.
Да, форму можно как то временно сохранять в БД, но сейчас речь не об этом, а о onbeforeunload. 
Соответственно можно переопределить этот метод и пользователь благополучно получит сообщение, что ай-ай-ай, ты пытаешься уйти и твои данные потеряются.

НО, браузер будет кидать это при любой попытке покинуть страницу. Соответсвенно как это надо обработать, чтобы браузер не делал этого, когда ты нажмешь таки на нужную кнопку? Просто перед тем как в нужном месте перейти на новую страницу сбросить onbeforeunload?

И более глобальный вопрос, насколько сейчас такие штуки вообще используются, есть ли им адекватная замена?

Comment: Можно при попытке покинуть страницу проверять, заполнены ли поля формы. Если да- выводить предупреждение

Comment: @Nikita Fedin Вы можете сохранять данные в сессии или localstorage. А для реализации описанного метода - FrogRider предложил Вам действительно стоящий вариант.